# Zip arrays with different size using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way in lodash to zip two arrays of different size, where the result would like this

```
_.zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1,2]) -> [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
```

So it should start just from the beginning if one array reach its end

Comment: Are you saying, you would like the second array to keep getting looped over, so if you had `a, b, c, d, e, f` you would get `a 1, b 2, c 1, d 2, e 1, f 2`??

Comment: where did b came from ?

Comment: @CallumLinington yes

Comment: @VinodLouis, sorry was a typo

Comment: I kind of think what is the point, zip code isn't difficult... you might as well implement the function yourself...

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new array, in which the 2nd array will be repeated, and then `_zip()` it with the original array.

The example assumes that the 2nd array is the shorter one.

```js
function repeatingZip(arr1, arr2) {
  var ratio = Math.ceil(arr1.length / arr2.length); // how many times arr2 fits in arr1
  var pattern = _(new Array(ratio)) // create a new array with the length of the ratio
    .fill(arr2) // fill each item with the 2nd array
    .flatten() // flatten it to an array
    .take(arr1.length) // remove redundant items
    .value();
  
  return _.zip(arr1, pattern);
}

var result = repeatingZip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], [1,2]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very nice. You could even replace the `slice` with `take(arr1.length)` to have one less parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [_.zipWith](https://lodash.com/docs#zipWith) function that allows you to modify the result of zip.

You can then sort out the size problem in a number of ways. In this one, I calculate the size difference and use it to provide a value when the function callback gets an undefined value (this happens when the size of one of the arrays is exceeded).

```js
var idxWrp = function(arr1, arr2) {
    var index = 0,
      diff = Math.abs(_.size(arr1) - _.size(arr2)) - 1;
    return function(a, b) {
      a = _.isUndefined(a) ? arr1[index % diff] : a;
      b = _.isUndefined(b) ? arr2[index % diff] : b;
      index++;
      return [a, b];
    };
  },
  arr1 = [1, 2, 3],
  arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  res = _.zipWith(arr1, arr2, idxWrp(arr1, arr2));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```